# withCount() for multiple levels?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, count, eager-loading

Like you can do `Project::with('events.contacts')` can you also do `Project::withCount('events.contacts')` ? It doesn't seem to work. Is there another way to find the total count of contacts for all events for a certain project where project.id = event.project_id and event.id = contact.event_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use relationship **Has Many Through**

> Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Contact::class, Event::class);
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
Project::withCount('contacts')->get();
```

Comment: Ah, you clever owl. I actually already have that relationship. I’ll try. Thanks!